# Run daemon on startup in Fedora 13 after wireless interface is up

Tags: networking, fedora, init-script

I want to have `radvd` (the IPv6 router advertisement daemon) run on startup on Fedora 13. However, the network interface that it will use must be up, otherwise the daemon won't start.

If I run the daemon manually when the system is running everything works fine.

However, I can't figure out how to tell the Fedora 13 init system "run radvd on boot but **only after** wlan0 is up". wlan0 is managed by NetworkManager and it would be nice if I could keep it that way.

I tried enabling `radvd` on boot using the GUI `system-config-services` tool; then `radvd` tries to start in the boot process (after NetworkManager) but fails because wlan0 does not exist. I also tried changing `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-wlan0` but that also didn't help (I don't understand exactly how the configuration in `/etc/sysconfig/networking/` interacts with NetworkManager).

It seems to me that this kind of thing should be straightforward with Upstart but I can't find an Upstart event that tells me "a network interface is up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too familiar with Fedora, but I know network manager does have a built-in system to run scripts after an interface comes up.  On Arch linux the scripts are located at

`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`

You will need to create a script to say when the interface is up, do this, when the interface is down do this.  In your case, start raddvd when the interface is up, and stop it when the interface is down.  Arch Linux's wiki has a bit more info and an example script that should get your going just fine.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Network_Services_with_NetworkManager_Dispatcher

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (you may have to adapt this for Fedora if it doesn't have the same chain):

- NetworkManager runs scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` when an interface comes up or down.
  In particular, `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown` runs the ifupdown scripts.
- Ifupdown runs scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-down.d`.
  In particular, `/etc/network/if-up.d/upstart` and `/etc/network/if-down.d/upstart` trigger Upstart events. Here's how you would catch these events in a service description:

  ```
  start on net-device-up IFACE=wlan0
  stop on net-device-down IFACE=wlan0
  ```

Comment: I still couldn't find an Upstart event triggered on Fedora, but I could write my own script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ to start the daemon. I have the feeling Fedora integrates Upstart considerably less than Ubuntu (they also plan to switch to systemd in F15). Great answer, thanks.