# Reload apache after network changes with systemd

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, dns

I have a Fedora 25 VM running in Hyper-V. This VM is used for a PHP app running on Apache. It is up-to-date and running stock everything.

A simple php script to connect to a remote website fails when running in Apache but works fine from the command line:

```
$host='tcp://www.shinyandnew.ca/';
$socket = stream_socket_client($host, $errno, $errstr, 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, stream_context_create());

if (!$socket) {
    print ("Unable to connect to ${host}: ${errno} ${errstr}\n");
} else {
    print ("Connected to ${host} successfully \n");
  fclose($socket);
}
```

The error is

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

However, the VM has network access and everything works fine from the php command line. This suggests it's an Apache issue. Also: if I restart Apache, the problem goes away.

Thus my question:

How can I force Apache to resolve names properly after a reboot? If I need to reload Apache after every network change, that's acceptable for this installation (it's a dev workstation): how do I trigger that automatically so that it works on boot? Is there a systemd method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to trigger a re-load or a re-start.  You simply need to ensure that Apache is not started until `/etc/resolv.conf` has been written by whatever is doing that at bootstrap.  The advice from the PHP bug tracker is to use a systemd override file to add an `After=` extension naming the relevant service(s) into `httpd.service`:

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
install -m 0755 -d httpd.d
echo >> httpd.d/after.conf "[Unit]"
echo >> httpd.d/after.conf "After=network.service systemd-networkd.service network-online.target"
```

## Further reading

- imacarthur (2017-04-20).  *[stream_socket_client fails without hosts entry](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74483)*. Bug #74483.  PHP bug tracker.

Comment: I had seen this bug report and tried to set the correct "After=" override but it didn't work. I tried again after seeing your answer which had "[Unit]" in the override file - this fixed the issue. I edited the file using `systemctl edit httpd` instead of creating it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Put an Apache reload script in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` folder.
Source: [Run daemon on startup in Fedora 13 after wireless interface is up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/run-daemon-on-startup-in-fedora-13-after-wireless-interface-is-up)

OR trigger Apache config reload from Upstart conf.

I mean somthing like

`start on net-device-up` - but this could be Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Fedora 25 is a systemd operating system, and the question is tagged [tag:systemd].